# Replacing a part of file path in exec

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, find, exec

I would like to replace the part of each file path, which will be find by find linux command.
My approach is attached below:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec echo {} | sed "s/f/u/g" {} \;
```

I expect the replacement of each letter "f" with "u" in file path. Unfortunately I got this error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
sed: can't read {}: No such file or directory
sed: can't read ;: No such file or directory
```

What I did wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `-exec` takes a single command name, not an arbitrary shell command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `I would like to replace the part of each file path`

If you want to change just the file names/paths then use:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'echo "$1" | sed "s/f/u/g"' - {} \;
```

or a bit more efficient with `xargs` (since it avoids spawning subshell for each found file):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 |
xargs -0 bash -c 'for f; do sed "s/f/u/g" <<< "$f"; done'
```

Comment: Your last solutions works perfect. Thank you. My case was an example only. Really I need to replace the beginning of file path (./) with "../directory" and copy each file to such modified directory structure. Basing on your script, I created something like this: find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'echo "$1" | sed "s/\.\//..\/directory\//g"' - {} \; Now I'm trying to add cp functionality. Anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: The first part would make `sed` read the found files and replace within its file content and this isn't what has been asked. Only the second part is correct, the first part has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Mecki: You're right.Thanks for catching it. I have edited this answer and provided a more efficient option using `xargs` as well.

Comment: @Viper Adding how you managed to cp from this could help other users, looking for the exact same thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | while read files
do 
newname=$(echo "${files}" | sed s"@f@u@"g)
mv -v "${files}" "${newname}"
done
```

I don't completely understand what you meant by file path.  If you weren't talking about the file name, please clarify further.

Comment: '@' is a common part of dir name on Synology. I'd go for '#' as separator